# Trying to run a simple docker container with a crontab and a simple python script

Tags: docker, cron, dockerfile, containers

So I am pretty new into creating containers and I have the simple Dockerfile where I would like to run a simple python script every minute:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron
COPY my_python /bin/my_python
COPY root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
RUN chmod +x /bin/my_python
CMD cron -l 2 -f
```

where my_python:

```
print("hi world!!")
```

and root:

```
* * * * * python3 /bin/my_python
```

then I just create the image and the container:

```
 docker image build -t python-test
 docker container run -it --name python-test python-test
```

I was supposed to see every minute a print with the hi world, however when running the container ( after the image build) no logs seem to appear.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I believe you want `-L 2` rather than `-l 2` in your `cron` command line; see the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/cron.8.html) for details.

The `cron` daemon logs to syslog, so if something isn't work as intended, it's a good idea to arrange to receive those messages. The `busybox` tool provides a simple syslog daemon that can log to an in-memory buffer and a tool for reading those logs, so I modified your `Dockerfile` to look like this:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron busybox
COPY my_python /bin/my_python
COPY root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
RUN chmod +x /bin/my_python
CMD busybox syslogd -C; cron -L 2 -f
```

After starting this, I `docker exec`'d into the container and ran `busybox logread` and found:

```
Jan 24 16:50:45 7f516db86417 cron.info cron[4]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 24 16:50:45 7f516db86417 cron.info cron[4]: (root) INSECURE MODE (mode 0600 expected) (crontabs/root)
Jan 24 16:50:45 7f516db86417 cron.info cron[4]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

So there's your problem: the permissions on the `root` crontab are incorrect. There are two ways to fix this problem:

1. We could explicitly `chmod` the file when we copy it into place, or
2. We can use the `crontab` command to install the file, which takes care of that for us

I like option 2 because it means we don't need to know the specifics of what `cron` expects in terms of permissions.  That gets us:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron busybox
COPY my_python /bin/my_python
COPY root /tmp/root.crontab
RUN crontab /tmp/root.crontab
RUN chmod +x /bin/my_python
CMD busybox syslogd -C; cron -L 2 -f
```

With that change, we can confirm that the cron job is now running as expected:

```
Jan 24 16:59:50 8aa688ad31cc syslog.info syslogd started: BusyBox v1.30.1
Jan 24 16:59:50 8aa688ad31cc cron.info cron[4]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 24 16:59:50 8aa688ad31cc cron.info cron[4]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Jan 24 17:00:01 8aa688ad31cc authpriv.err CRON[7]: pam_env(cron:session): Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory
Jan 24 17:00:01 8aa688ad31cc authpriv.info CRON[7]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 24 17:00:02 8aa688ad31cc cron.info CRON[7]: (root) END (python3 /bin/my_python)
Jan 24 17:00:02 8aa688ad31cc authpriv.info CRON[7]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

But...there's still no output from the container! If you read through that man page, you'll find this:

> cron then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs,
> checking each  command  to see  if  it  should  be run in the current
> minute.  When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of
> the crontab (or  to  the  user  named  in  the  MAILTO  environment
> variable  in  the  crontab,  if  such  exists)...

In other words, `cron` collects the output from programs and attempts
to mail to the user who owns the cron job. If you want to see the
output from the `cron` job on the console, you will need to explicitly
redirect stdout, like this:

```
* * * * * python3 /bin/my_python > /dev/console
```

With this change in place, running the image results in the message...

```
hi world!
```

...printing to the console once a minute.

Comment: What makes SO so good are the explanations from people like you. I just have 2 questions to ask:
1-  from the `busybox logread` what is the log `Unable to open env file: /etc/default/locale: No such file or directory` for?
2-  Regarding the "output is mailed to the owner" what are the options other than the `/dev/console` . Could not find it in the man doc. THANK YOU again for the awesome explanation.

Comment: Re: the first question, something is trying to figure out the current locale (for proper character encoding), but it isn't configured in the container. That warning is safe to ignore. Re: the second question, other options are infinite: that's just simple shell redirection (`> /path/to/a/file`), so you can send it to any file of your choice. But if you want it to show up on the container's `stdout`, that is `/dev/console`.